# Extract all keys from nested Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested Python dictionary, with lower levels containing lists of dictionaries. The nesting goes up to 7 levels.

My sample data:

```
d = {'a':'ewr0',
    'b':1234,
    'c':{'c1':1234,'c2':456},
    'd':[{'d1':123, 'd2':[12,23,34,45,56], 'd3':{'d4':98,'d5':87}},{'d6':1,'d7':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'d8':{'d9':10,'d10':11}}]}
```

I would like to loop through each key, print out/append to list what type of value is held.

- If the value is a dictionary, say that it is a dictionary, and in the nested one perform the same test.
- If the value is a list, cycle through each element of the list, and state what type each element is. And depending on the type, carry out the same analysis.

For the above, I would like to have a result:

```
a: string
b: int
c: dict of length 2
   c1: int
   c2: int
d: list of 2 elements
   ele 1: dict of length 3
      d1: int
      d2: list of 5 int/string elements
      d3: dict of length 2
          d4: int
          d5: int
   ele 2: dict of length 3
      d6: int
      d7: list of 6 int/string elements
      d8: dicts of length 2
          d9: int
          d10: int
```

I am able to extract key info from the first level, but not sure how to get the lower levels with:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    print(f'{key} holds value of type:{type(value)}')
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        print(f'\tdict has length {len(value)}')
        for key2, value2 in value:
            print(f'\t{key} holds value of type:{type(value)}')
    if isinstance(value, list):
        print(f'\tthe list has {len(value)} elements')
        for j in range(len(value)):
            print(f'\t{type(value[j])}')
```

What do I need to do to search deeper into the dictionary, without adding more `if's`? How can I extract information if the levels deeper than what is currently shown? Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to use something called **recursion**. You call the same function on the inner dictionaries, so they will in turn print their own keys and types of values.

Comment: This would be easier with some more consistency - e.g. why is `d: list of 2 elements` but `d2: list of 4 int/string elements` (actually 5 and they're _all_ int). For example [this](https://gist.github.com/textbook/25e682cc71e3195262946af9f3c66a6f) would be much easier to get to.

Comment: @matszwecja, I will look at recursion, thanks
.@jonrsharpe, I used `int/str` bc they might also be string. Your example is correct, and I updated mine accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursion is the right approach. You can use a helper function (I named it `print_type_w_len`) to print type with length when dealing with `dict` and `list`, thus avoiding repetition:

```
d = {'a':'ewr0',
    'b':1234,
    'c':{'c1':1234,'c2':456},
    'd':[{'d1':123, 'd2':[12,23,34,45,56], 'd3':{'d4':98,'d5':87}},{'d6':1,'d7':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'d8':{'d9':10,'d10':11}}]}

def print_type_w_len(v, k, level):
    if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
        print('\t' * level + f'{k}: {type(v).__name__} of length {len(v)}')
        print_elt_types(v, level+1)
    else:
        print('\t' * level + f'{k}: {type(v).__name__}')

def print_elt_types(o, level=0):
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        for key, value in o.items():
            print_type_w_len(value, key, level)
            
    elif isinstance(o, list):
        for i, e in enumerate(o, start=1):
            print_type_w_len(e, f'ele {i}', level)

    else:
        print(f'Single element of type {type(o).__name__}')

print_elt_types(d)
```

Output:

```
a: str
b: int
c: dict of length 2
        c1: int
        c2: int
d: list of length 2
        ele 1: dict of length 3
                d1: int
                d2: list of length 5
                        ele 1: int
                        ele 2: int
                        ele 3: int
                        ele 4: int
                        ele 5: int
                d3: dict of length 2
                        d4: int
                        d5: int
        ele 2: dict of length 3
                d6: int
                d7: list of length 6
                        ele 1: int
                        ele 2: int
                        ele 3: int
                        ele 4: int
                        ele 5: int
                        ele 6: int
                d8: dict of length 2
                        d9: int
                        d10: int
```

Comment: `type(v) in [dict, list]` -> `isinstance(v, (dict, list))`. Also `print_type_w_len` doens't use any closure variables so can be defined _once_.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I made the changes in my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can user recursion, here is example for infinite depth.

```
def parse_dict(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for key, value in d.items():
            print(f"Key: {key}, Value: {value}")
            parse_dict(value)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for item in d:
            parse_dict(item)
    else:
        print(f'Value {d}')
```